# Executing different query for different conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, conditional-statements

It's simple

i have table X, Y and Z

query A will select row from table X

if query A result is exist, SELECT from table Y
if query A result is NOT exist, SELECT from table Z

i need the know how to write the query

Comment: sample data and desired output will help us to help you. May be LEFT JOIN will be enough

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT * FROM Y WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM X)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Z WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM X);
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZnSJfh0n)